# Generating a Midi (or chart preferably) file from mp3 onsets

Tags: python, python-3.x, librosa

I am using librosa's onset function to generate onsets for an mp3. Is there away I can turn this in to Midi format?

Comment: take a look at this library - https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi

Comment: Thanks for this! It allows the use of timings!

Comment: The python 3 library is [here](https://github.com/louisabraham/python3-midi) if anyone is looking!